# Better way to handle Arrays concatenation placed inside the Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Well, I need to make an array concatenation, placed inside the `Object`.

So the worked solution I've made is:

```
      const usersList = {
        tester: [{ id: 1, //... }, //...],
        custumers: [{ id: 1, //... }, //...],
        admin: [{ id: 1, //... }, //...]
      }

      let allUsers = []

      Object.keys(usersList).forEach(listKey => {
        allUsers = [
          ...allUsers,
          ...usersList[listKey]
        ]
      })

      return allUsers
```

Besides, I wonder perhaps there is present a much fashionable way to deal with such a case? I tried this one, but it doesn't work:

```
[...Object.keys(usersList).map(listKey => usersList[listKey])]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the object's values, which will give you an array of arrays, then flatten:

```
const allUsers = Object.values(usersList).flat();
```

If you can't use `.flat`, then:

```
const allUsers = [].concat.apply(...Object.values(usersList));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use `flatMap`

```js
const usersList = {
  tester: [{ id: 1 }],
  custumers: [{ id: 1 }],
  admin: [{ id: 1 }]
};

const res = Object.values(usersList).flatMap(x => x);

console.log(res);
```